# How to fill a combobox from a MS Access text field then insert combobox selection into another table

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert an Access table record with information from a combobox. I am using a winform and C#. I have simplified my project to just include the problem area. I am showing three methods with 4 controls (2 buttons and 2 comboboxes. The first method is connecting to an Access database and then showing a list of the tables and views in the first combobox. this method will also call the last method, SelectName() and fill the second combobox with field contents from a predetermined table from the selected database. The second method (buttonInsert_Click()) is where my problem lies. I would like the method to insert into one of the selected tables from combobox1 the selected item from combobox2 when the insert button is clicked. The only content I can get to insert into the selected table is

```
                     System.Data.DataRowView
```

The C# section of my project is below. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank You.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace DbApp
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private char ch = '"';
        private OleDbConnection dbConn;
        private string sql = "";


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "";
        string stringData = "";

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "";
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        stringData = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ch + Text + ch;

        if (dbConn != null)
            dbConn.Close();

        dbConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        dbConn.Open();
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        DataTable info = dbConn.GetSchema("Tables");
        for (int x = 0; x < info.Rows.Count; ++x)
        {
            if ((info.Rows[x][3].ToString() == "TABLE") || (info.Rows[x][3].ToString() == "VIEW"))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add((object)info.Rows[x][2].ToString());
            }
        }

        SelectName();
    }

    private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = this.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

        try
        {
            dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
            dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + ch + openFileDialog1.FileName + ch;
            dbConn.Open();

            sql = "INSERT INTO " + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " (Names)" +
            "Values (@name)";
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            myCommand.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + err.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void SelectName()
    {
        string strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + ch + openFileDialog1.FileName + ch;

        try
        {
            using (dbConn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
            {
                dbConn.Open();
                sql = "SELECT Name FROM Names";
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn));
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "Names");
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                this.comboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables["Names"];
                this.comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string name = this.comboBox2.Text;
```

Comment: Combobox1 is working like it should. The problem is with combox2, the selected item does not have a value, which is i belive why System.Data.DataRowView is added to the table.

Comment: Does your combobox show the value you want to insert as `name`?  If so then you should easily be able to access it via `SelectedValue` or `Text` property of `comboBox2`.  Regardless - you can try the edited solution above.

Comment: The Text property did the trick. My string declaration became string name = this.comboBox2.Text.ToString();  Thank you for your help.